# Getting duplicate records in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle10g

I have 3 tables: `order`, `order_transaction` and `order_history`.

In `order` only one entry of order along with `order_id` is saved.
    In `order_history` I save all transaction occurring on that order like `orderAccepted`, `orderInProgress` (this are events on that order).
    In `order_transaction` all transaction related details are saved. The `transaction_id` in both table ie `order_transaction` and `order_history` remains same.

```
content of tables are 
order
    id
    created by
    created_date
    client type
    type 
    qty 
    price

order_history
    id
    order_id
    transaction_id
    events
    created_date

order_transaction
    id
    order_id
    transaction_id
    qty
    price
    status
```

There is an event where in customer can revert there order called `orderProccessedReverted` but it's not done in one go. For example if there was a order of 1000 qty and then it was reverted it will be split in to 10 different entries where `order_id` will remain same but transaction will change and this entry will be present in both `order_transaction` and `order_history` tables.

Example of entries in both table would be:

```
order_history
id  order_id  transaction_id  events                        created_date  
001  1111       345           orderProccessedReverted       20-08-19
002  1111       346           orderProccessedReverted       20-08-19
003  1111       347           orderProccessedReverted       20-08-19


order_transaction
id  order_id  transaction_id    qty     created_date  
011  1111       345             100      20-08-19
012  1111       346             100      20-08-19
013  1111       347             100      20-08-19
```

Now I'm generating a report where I need all orders that are reverted. Following are reports columns:

```
order_id   created_by   client_type  transaction_id   qty    status          events                     created_date
111         user1           type1       444           100    reverted       orderProccessedReverted         20-08-19
111         user1           type1       445           100    reverted       orderProccessedReverted         20-08-19
111         user1           type1       446           100    reverted       orderProccessedReverted         20-08-19
111         user1           type1       447           100    reverted       orderProccessedReverted         20-08-19
112         user2           type2       551           50     reverted       orderProccessedReverted         20-08-19
112         user2           type2       552           50     reverted       orderProccessedReverted         20-08-19
112         user2           type2       553           50     reverted       orderProccessedReverted         20-08-19
```

I tried doing left join and normal joins but I got duplicate records.

I tried following query:

```
select * from
order_history orderHist,
order_transaction  tr,
order ord
where
ord.id = tr.order_id
AND  tr.order_id = orderhist.order_id
AND tr.transaction_id = orderhist.transaction_id 
AND orderhist.event= 'orderProccessedReverted'
AND tr.status = 'REVERTED'
AND ord.tradedate='20190820';
```

Comment: You should prefer the ANSI join syntax, rather than the old Oracle join syntax. It was already available even in ancient Oracle 10g

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit i tried JOIN and LEFT JOIN too.

Comment: @Suyash: you are not showing sample data for table `order, can you add it? Also would you please show the output that you would expect, given your sample data?

Comment: @Suyash Provide expected output for report and also, how many entry will be there in ord table. Query you have provided will give duplicate records as there are multiplee entry in order_history and order_transaction.

Comment: Try `FROM order_history orderHist 
 join order_transaction  tr ON tr.order_id = orderhist.order_id AND tr.transaction_id = orderhist.transaction_id 
 join ORDER ord on ord.id = tr.order_id`

Comment: Your example data does not match your table structure (`order_transaction` has `created_date` in the example data but not in the list of columns and there is no `qty`, `price` or `status` in your example data) and neither matches your query (`ord.tradedate` does not exist and `orderhist.event` is missing the `s`). Please [edit] your question with valid DDL statements for your tables, DML statements for your example data and an SQL query that will run against them to give us a [MRE] (and include your expected output).

Comment: please check my question now, I have updated it

Comment: @Suyash where is duplicate records? output you have provided is having unique records. Please output of you query.

Comment: @MT0 m sorry i actually gave preference to columns which we can join so i missed it

Comment: @MansiRaval i M geting around 20-25 rows for each record_id

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit tried this Sir, didnt work

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=329d003a90fbbb2bfd7c9a98d2cd9edc) Not seeing any duplicates.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. Put this as text in your post.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, I have create with dummy data and few columns, you can add more column in select.

```sql
WITH ord AS ( SELECT '001' AS id,
       '111' AS order_id
FROM dual ), ord_his AS ( ( SELECT '001' AS id,
       '111' AS order_id,
       '456' AS transaction_id,
       'Reverted' AS events
FROM dual
) UNION ( SELECT '002' AS id,
       '111' AS order_id,
       '457' AS transaction_id,
       'Reverted' AS events
FROM dual
) ), ord_tran AS ( ( SELECT '001' AS id,
       '111' AS order_id,
       '456' AS transaction_id,
       100 AS qnty
FROM dual
) UNION ( SELECT '002' AS id,
       '111' AS order_id,
       '457' AS transaction_id,
       100 AS qnty
FROM dual
) ) SELECT ord.*,
       ord_his.transaction_id,
       events,
       qnty
FROM ord,
     ord_his,
     ord_tran
WHERE ord.order_id = ord_his.order_id AND ord_his.transaction_id = ord_tran.transaction_id;
```

Comment: still gives duplicate.

Comment: provide the data you are using